# Проверка наличия элемента строки в динамическом массиве

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Имеются строки вида

```
GPGSV,3,1,10,27,13,078,43,05,31,307,48,16,24,042,43,02,10,267,43
GPGSV,3,2,10,26,03,031,36,07,75,215,51,09,57,121,53,30,40,234,50
GPGSV,3,3,10,23,29,117,46,04,36,114,46
GPGSV,3,1,10,27,13,078,43,05,31,307,48,16,24,042,43,02,10,267,43
GPGSV,3,2,10,26,03,031,36,07,75,215,51,09,57,121,53,30,40,234,50
GPGSV,3,3,10,23,29,117,46,04,36,114,46
```

Есть необходимые значения в строке после определенного количества запятых, нужно проверить, есть ли это значение в массиве, если нет, то вывести это значение и добавить его в массив, если есть, то пропустить.
Значения изначально неизвестны, максимум их может быть 100.

```
int main() {
    int k;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream logs_("C:/Users/Olya/Desktop/LogGLO.txt"); // Откуда берем данные
    std::ofstream pout("C:/Users/Olya/Desktop/outLOG.txt"); // Куда загружаем

    // Работа с массивом 
    int num = 100;
    int* MASS = new int[num];
    bool ExitFlag;

    if (logs_.is_open()) {
        while (getline(logs_, line)) {
            k = 0;
            if (line.substr(0, 5) == "GPGSV") {
                for (size_t i = 0, N = 4; i < line.size(); i++) {
                    if (line[i] == ',') k++;
                    if (k == N) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < num; f++) {
                            if (MASS[j] != stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2))) {
                                ExitFlag = false;
                                MASS[j] = stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2));
                            }
                        }
                        if (ExitFlag == false) {
                            pout << "Satellite name: " << line.substr(i + 1, 2) << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            logs_.close();
            std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else std::cout << "File is not open" << '\n';
    pout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

С поиском значений проблем нет, реализовала через подсчет количества запятых, а вот с динамическим массивом не понимаю. Пробовала проверять его на наличие элементов превращая их в тип int через stoi, но компилятор ругается, на строки

```
if (Memory[f] != stoi(line.substr(i + 1, 2)))
```

и

```
pout << "Satellite name: " << line.substr(i + 1, 2) << std::endl;
```

"Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7748C41F в ParsingLogs.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::invalid_argument по адресу памяти 0x0036F2F4."

Comment: Так компилятор ругаеться или падает во время выполнения?

Comment: i < line.size()  Соответственно у вас выход за границу массива. Простое правило. Если вместо переменной у вас формула (I+1 тоже формула), то подставьте в нее крайние значения.

Comment: `stoi` бросает `invalid_argument` когда строка начинается не с цифры (перед цифрой могут быть только пробельные символы)

Comment: @becouse часть массива с i работала без проблем, проблемы начались, когда я во внутрь прикрутила еще один массив j, который по-идее должен проверять значение, которое получилось через массив i и заполнять их в себя, если встречается его в первый раз.

Comment: @EOF До этого я проверяла работу массива i, он выводил значения просто цифры, без каких то посторонних символов

Comment: `stoi` также бросает `invalid_argument` если передать пустую строку

Comment: @EOF Проверила еще раз, не хватало N+=4;, тк потом он начинал выводить значения с запятой, но программа теперь просто ничего не выводит.